# Filter with custom lambda over three columns where one value exists and and three others are absent

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have sheet2 that has `colF`, `colG` and `colH` and I need to be able grab the rows where one row has value A and Value B and Value C and Value D are not present in one of the other two columns in the same row.

For Example:

```
G,G,F                   
G,C,D           
C,D,A   
B,A,B       
B,B,A   
C,A,D           
A,G,F                           
G,B,A           
A,G,G
```

This example has two row that have just as A or an A without the presence of B or C or D in either of the other two columns.

Here is my gross attempt at this:

```
=QUERY('Sheet2'!$B$2:$M,"Select * where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
```

Do I need to use a Nested `IF` inside the the Query?

Comment: What would be your desired output? Can you share a sample workbook showing your input and expected result?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ON56i72PCajC0VK-K2a8pDGb2K7AtBQuN7vGEUyhJ54/edit?usp=sharing  I need the formula on sheet one to only show the rows have a DD and do NOT HAVE PKW or CKR or EB in the two columns..  It will check Columns D E F for these values.

Comment: The columns can have other values in them. Just not PKW OR CKR OR EB

Comment: Beautiful thank you sir!! I usually use QUERY.. But I Like this filter! I learned a bunch just now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following formula-

```
=FILTER(Sheet2!A2:F,
BYROW(Sheet2!D2:F,LAMBDA(x,LET(tmp,TEXTJOIN("|",1,x),NOT((REGEXMATCH(tmp,"PKW|CKR|EB")))*(REGEXMATCH(tmp,"DD"))))))
```

[image]

Comment: `REGEXMATCH()` allow you to compare multiple strings at a time.